# xcode 5.1 - how do I remove plug in?

Tags: plugins, xcode5

This must have been asked before, but I can't find a reference.

I have low vision and -- between projects -- want to change the font size and spacing between lines*.

I stupidly added a plug-in, and now I cannot figure out how to get rid of it properly.

Any help appreciated.

*how do i do this too? and the sidebar text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug-ins can be found at `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`. You can delete it from there.